# How can I convert a vector iterator to an int value to print it?

Tags: c++

I keep getting an error while running this code. I've searched for a solution for similar errors, but as a junior programmer, I can't understand solutions meant to be for different codes.
Here is my code. Please give me a solution with demonstration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        vector <int> listed_elements {10,6,11};
        auto min_value = min_element(listed_elements.begin(), listed_elements.end()); 
        cout << "The smallest element on the list is: ";
        cout << min_value << endl;

        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that you've literally been searching for *converting*, and that's not what you want to do. Check out the [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If you want the value referenced by the iterator, use `*min_value` (after checking that `min_value != listed_elements.end()`, to avoid undefined behaviour)   If you want to convert into an index (where `0` corresponds to the first element) do `std::distance(listed_elements.begin(), min_value)`.

Comment: @Peter `std::min_element` never returns `end` does it? Anyhow I will add a note to the answer...

Comment: @Peter it does in case the range is empty

Comment: @idclev463035818 -  Indeed.  An alternative test in that case is that the vector is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterators mimick pointers. You can dereference the iterator to get the element:

```
cout << *min_value << endl;
```

Note that in general algorithms often return `end` (the iterator you passed as second parameter) to signal that no element was found and then you need to check that you have a valid iterator **before** dereferencing it:

```
if (min_value != listed_elements.end()) {
    std::cout << *min_value << std::endl;
}
```

However, the only case where `std::min_element` returns the end iterator is when the range is empty, so in case you are absolutely certain that this isn't the case you can drop that check (but only then!).